# Angle between 2 faces of tetrahedron

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Two faces ABC and DBC of a tetrahedron ABCD are right-angled triangles with $\angle ACB = \angle DCB = 90^{\circ}$.
>
> Given that the edge DA is perpendicular to the face $ABC$, $\angle CBD = 45^{\circ}$ and the angle between the line $DB$ and the face $ABC$ is $30^{\circ}$.
>
> Find the angle between the two faces $ABC$ and $DBC$.

I am not sure how to go about this problem. I made a paper tetrahedron to try and visualize this problem better, and what I get is that the angle should be $45^{\circ}$. I am however not able to make the connection on how to go about proving this.

Can you guys please help me figure this out? Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $C$ at the origin, $B$ on the $x$-axis, and $A$ on the $y$-axis; $D$ is in the $yz$-plane, $\overline{DA}$ is perpendicular to the $xy$-plane, $\overline{DB}$ makes a $30$º degree angle with the $xy$-plane (so that $\angle DBA = 30$º), $\angle CBD = 45$º, and what’s wanted is $\angle DCA$.

$\triangle DCB$ is an isosceles right triangle; there is no harm in assuming that $|CB| = 1$, in which case $|CD| = 1$, and $|DB| = \sqrt 2$. $\angle BAD$ is a right angle, since $\overline{DA}$ is perpendicular to the $xy$-plane, and $\angle DBA = 30$º, so $\triangle DBA$ is a $30-60-90$ right triangle, and $|DA| = \frac{|DB|}{2} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. Finally, $\triangle DCA$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $|DC| = 1$ and leg $|DA| = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$, so the remaining side is $\sqrt{1^2 - \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \right)^2}= \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$, $\triangle DCA$ is an isosceles right triangle, and $\angle DCA$ is indeed $45$º.

This is a little more than I should probably say for homework, but I’ve deliberately been a bit concise, and you’re still going to have to visualize it properly to follow the calculations.

Comment: Can you please explain why $\triangle DCA$ is a right triangle? Thanks for your help, the fog is starting to clear up!

Comment: Aha! got it, $DA \perp face ABC$, hence by definition $DA \perp AC$, hence...

Comment: There you go! Always nicer when you can do it yourself, isn’t it?

Comment: Yup! Your solution is pretty much complete, but it was good to follow the correct line of reasoning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If the angle between $DB$ and face $ABC$ is $30^\circ$, then (by definition) the angle between $DB$ and a line perpendicular to $ABC$ is $60^\circ$; draw in such a perpendicular: namely, let $P$ be the point on $AC$ such that $DP \perp AC$ (and thus $DP \perp ABC$, so that also $BP \perp DP$).

Use $\triangle BCD$ and then $\triangle BDP$ to determine the lengths of segments $BD$ and $DP$ in turn; then you should be able to determine $\angle ACD$, which (because $BD \perp \triangle ACD$) is equal to the desired dihedral angle.

(Hmmmm ... I didn't seem to need the fact that $DA \perp \triangle BCD$.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try to work it out with this method and get back later.

Comment: You are right, the 30-60-90 triangle can be implied. Regarding the $\perp$ wouldn't point $C$ be same as $P$, since they are right-triangles?